How to subset SNP data?
I received genomic data from 429 cowpea samples that were sequenced, I would like to know if I can subset this data to select only 110 samples to use for my research. Note that the data is SNP in HapMap format. Please give me some clues. Thank you

We will likely need a lot more information before we can make any suggestions. Why only 110 rather than all? What are the characteristics of the samples and the data? What other data do you have (phenotypes?)? What are some approaches that you've considered? What is your research question?

Not sure what you want to categorise/subset by, but you can definitely subset your HapMap genomic data to select 110 samples.
First, identify the sample IDs you wish to retain. Open the HapMap file in a text editor or use a programming language like Python or R. You can use the data.table or dplyr packages to filter columns corresponding to your selected sample IDs in R. In Python, use pandas to read the file into a DataFrame and select the desired columns. Make sure you include the header and the first few columns (marker information) in your subset. Save the filtered data back to a file in the same format.
